# How to add Microsoft Office 14 PIA into VS2015?

Tags: visual-studio-2015, office-interop

I've downloaded and installed the **Microsoft Office 2010 Primary Interop Assemblies** but my VS2015 doesn't seem to pick it up at all, and I've read many that there is supposed to be a .NET tab in the **Add References** window in VS2013, but that seems to be gone in VS2015...

I could see the MS Office 15 PIA under the COM tab though... can someone point me to the right direction to properly add the v14.0 PIA into VS2015? I can't seem to find the answer from Google and MSDN either... ugh

Answer (score 0):

I had trouble as well. I used these new projects to solve the issue as to which references were needed.

[image: Open New Project]

Then I added the two projects to my project only to have access their references. I right clicked on the office references I think I needed and copied the file location. I then used browse in the add reference and pasted in the reference file location in my project.

Here are the ones I ended up with in my project:

[image]

It was a real PIA! I tried all sorts of different ways to do this. One of the guys I work with has Office 2016 which trivial to get working with code. I am still on Office 2013. You will run into error messages if the VS2015 projects don't load or build. At least with the messages I could figure out what I needed to do to get those projects to build without errors. I tried referencing the projects VS made in my project to get access to their references. That didn't work. Copying the file location did. HTH.